# Excel Macro to select the each values from drop down list and copy-paste the values

Tags: vba, excel, drop-down-menu

I have excel sheet which has lot of calculation based on the values available in drop-down list in B1.

So far what i have done is,
 1. Created a drown down list in cell B1 in sheet "ACCM Configurator" based on the range from sheet "Analysis - Template" $A:$A (ignored blanks)
 2. Based on the value selected the down list in cell B1, I have created many calculations using formula in places those in A6:J33 in sheet "ACCM Configurator"

What I want to achieve now is,
 1. select each values in drop down list in B1 and copy the calculated values for each drop-down values from the range A6:J33 and paste in a new sheet called as "ACCM Append"
 2. Ignore any blank rows
 3. A5:J5 has headers, so expected this to be paste as a header in sheet "ACCM Append"

Answer (score 1):

if paste as new range

```
Sub DropDown1_Change()
'A6:J33 range
rangeCopy = Sheets("ACCM Configurator").range(Cells(6, 1), Cells(33, 10)).value
lastR = Sheets("ACCM Append").range("a:f").Find(What:="*", After:=Sheets("ACCM Append").Cells(1, 1), SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlFormulas).row
'paste after last used range
Sheets("ACCM Append").Cells(lastR + 1, "A").Resize(UBound(rangeCopy, 1), UBound(rangeCopy, 2)).value = rangeCopy
 End sub
```

if paste in same range

```
Sub DropDown1_Change()
'A6:J33 range
rangeCopy = Sheets("ACCM Configurator").range(Cells(6, 1), Cells(33, 10)).value
'paste after last used range
Sheets("ACCM Append").Cells(2, "A").Resize(UBound(rangeCopy, 1), UBound(rangeCopy, 2)).value = rangeCopy
 End sub
```

Note what on Sheets("ACCM Append") in first row must be headers values

Comment: Sorry on delay on response, 1st macro gives me a debug on 4th line and 2nd one does not select all the values in the list, it just select one values which is already in the drop down. Is it anything to do with the range?

Comment: Sorry on delay on response, 1st macro gives me a debug on 4th line and 2nd one does not select all the values in the list, it just select one values which is already in the drop down. Is it anything to do with the range?